# Is there any way to assign a select query to local variable in PL/SQL other than select into statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to assign a select query to local variable in PL/SQL other than select into statement?. Because select into throwing null value exception if the select query returns null value.  Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null value exception" in PL/SQL. Please **[edit]** your question and add the code you have a problem with (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please) and the full text of the error message you get.

Comment: As you are new here, please be aware that in order to make your question useful for others as well as the answers provided, we need the code you want to run and what is the problem, if so, you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to post your code, but here is an example that should show the behavior you need.  Assume there is a table called courses_tbl:

```
declare
cnumber number := NULL;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
     SELECT course_number
     FROM courses_tbl
     WHERE course_name = 'XYZ';

BEGIN

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into cnumber;

   if c1%notfound then
     -- Do something here if you care about not found.
     cnumber := 999; -- whatever
   end if;
```

you can read about cursor attributes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/named-cursor-attribute.html#GUID-CD8D8415-FF19-4D81-99BA-7825FD40CC96)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you need to use the `exception` handling as follows:

```
... -- Your procedure other code
BEGIN
 SELECT <COLUMN_NAME> INTO <YOUR_VARIABLE>
   FROM .....
  WHERE ....
EXCEPTION WHEN NO DATA FOUND THEN
  <YOUR_VARIABLE> := NULL;
END;
... -- Your procedure other code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...INTO...`:

```
DECLARE
  nCnumber  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CNUMBER FROM COURSES_TBL WHERE CNUMBER = 1'
    INTO nCnumber;
    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SELECT #1 : nCnumber = ' || nCnumber);
  
  nCnumber := NULL;
  
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CNUMBER FROM COURSES_TBL WHERE CNUMBER = 100'
      INTO nCnumber;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SELECT #2 : nCnumber = ' || nCnumber);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SELECT #2 : NO DATA FOUND');
  END;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f7cd04c0e1f0bdd11e869c03d0720ac)

Answer (score 1):

You've seen how to do it using a cursor or `exception` handling section (which is - in my opinion - the right way to do it). However, as we're *discussing*, here's yet another option - an aggregate function. It won't return `NO_DATA_FOUND` but `NULL`.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_job    emp.job%type;
  3  begin
  4    select job
  5      into l_job
  6      from emp
  7      where ename = 'Does not exist';
  8  end;
  9  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

This is what you might do:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_job    emp.job%type;
  3  begin
  4    select max(job)
  5      into l_job
  6      from emp
  7      where ename = 'Does not exist';
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```